# eslint don't show all warnings on yarn start in MAC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

I was working with react/angular in windows OS using visual code for the last 3 years and when I use npm start or yarn start It always shows the warning for all files with the message "compiled with warning" and in realtime it updates the warnings each time I save a file, now I changed my workstation to a macbook, installed VS code, ESlint extension and when I run npm or yarn start now It don't show any warning "compiled successfully" only when I open a file and save a change It shows the warnings only for that file, I tried change the vs setting.json adding "eslint.lintTask.enable": true, but still didn't work, please help because is hard to open each project file to view the eslint warnings

Comment: I was wondering about this too, I realised that when you run `yarn start` for the first time after project setup it will show all warnings, but then it shows warnings only for updated files or when you pull changes from remote. Then after you restart `yarn start` command it shows `compiled successfully`. I think it caches reviewed files but I could be wrong. It's ok for me because I still can view all warnings in vscode warnings window

Comment: @Mike you are right, I tested deleting all node_modules and running again yarn install/start and shows all the error, but how can I avoid to need to delete everything to view all the projects warnings in realtime

Comment: this issue still in progress https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11809, you can add env variable `CI=true` to treat warnings as errors or configure start script to clear cache as shown here https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11809#issuecomment-1130493431